# Rails loop with heading

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this loop in Rails and I want to list each associated `region_id` under each `region.name`. So far under each `region.name` I get a list of all items.

```
Region has_many :trials
Trials belongs_to :region, :primary_key => 'region_id'
```

**View**

```
  <% @regions.each do |region, list| %>
        <h3><%= region.region.name %></h3>
        <table class="table">
        <% list.each do |list| %>
            <tr>
            <td>
          <%= link_to list.site.site_name, trial_trials_path(trial_id: list.trial_id) unless list.site.site_name.blank? %>
            </td>
            <td>    
            <%= link_to list.trial_type, trial_trials_path(trial_id: list.trial_id) unless list.trial_type.blank? %>
            </td>
            <td>    
            <%= link_to list.grower.name, trial_trials_path(trial_id: list.trial_id) unless list.grower.name.blank? %>
            </td>
            </tr>
        <% end %>
        </table>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
 def index
 list = Trial.where('year = ?', Time.now.year).order(:region_id)
 @regions = list.group_by { |t| t.region_id }
 end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller, you have to group your items by region, using group_by added to your where close

In your view, you can then iterate through your items with @list[region].each

Comment: Thanks Danny, I have updated my code above. I can list the region_id's fine and it list all associated id's as well, but I get a **undefined method `region' for 2:Fixnum** error when trying to generate the name of the region via the region table.

Comment: why don't you group by t.region.name? The way you've written it now, the lists will be grouped by region_id. In your view, you then try to access the region of that region_id, which doesn't work...

Comment: and don't forget to add an include to your query as well. Saves you a lot of database queries...

Comment: Thanks for your help Danny, I managed to work out the issue. I had to join my regions table to my list query then group by t.region.name.